# How to add headers above the columns of a table in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started working with Python for a programming class.

One of the problems states:

You have encountered the Stirling approximation
ln(n!) ≈ n ln(n) − n
in Statistical Thermodynamics and may wonder how good (or bad) this approximation is for
small numbers. This is easily verified by making use of the Python math library, which
provides access to the natural logarithm as well as the factorial function.
Write a small Python script to print n, ln(n!), n ln(n) – n, and the relative error:
error = (ln(n!) − (n ln(n) − n)) / ln(n!)
in a table for values of n from 2 up to 1000.

I am able to process the data itself (below presented for 2 to 9 for simplicity):

```
>>> for x in range(2,10):
...     a = math.log(math.factorial(x))
...     b = x*math.log(x) - x
...     c = (a-b)/a
...     print(x, '\t', a, '\t', b, '\t', c)
```

which results in:

```
2        0.6931471805599453      -0.6137056388801094     1.8853900817779268
3        1.791759469228055       0.2958368660043291      0.8348903013573665
4        3.1780538303479458      1.5451774444795623      0.5137975858922471
5        4.787491742782046       3.0471895621705016      0.3635102208239511
6        6.579251212010101       4.750556815368331       0.2779487114435725
7        8.525161361065415       6.621371043387192       0.2233142854483519
8        10.60460290274525       8.635532333438686       0.18568074517875863
9        12.801827480081469      10.775021196025975      0.15832163706385113
```

I would like to put headers above the column but I don't know how. I've tried putting another print command above the for x in range command but then it just prints the headers on their own first. There are plenty of tutorials explaining about headers but those do not concern tables containing formulas and generated data but instead fixed values that are manually put in the cells.

Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check libraries such as numpy and pandas to get the real potential in numerical computation with python. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

a = []
b = []
c = []
x = [i for i in range(2,10)]

for el in x:
    ac = math.log(math.factorial(el))
    a.append(ac)
    bc = el*math.log(el) - el
    b.append(bc)
    c.append((ac-bc)/ac)

array = np.vstack((x,a,b,c))

df = pd.DataFrame(array.T, columns=["x", "a", "b", "c"])

print(df.head())
df.to_excel("table.xlsx", index=False)
```